# Abstract Design Pattern implementation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I started learning design patterns a while ago (only covered facade and abstract so far, but am enjoying it). I'm looking to apply the Abstract pattern to a problem I have.  The problem is: Supporting various Database systems using one abstract class and a set of methods and properties, which then the underlying concrete classes (inheriting from abstract class) would be implementing.

I have created a DatabaseWrapper abstract class and have create SqlClientData and MSAccessData concrete class that inherit from the DatabaseWrapper.

However, I'm still a bit confused about how the pattern goes as far as implementing these classes on the Client.

Would I do the following?:

```
DatabaseWrapper sqlClient = new SqlClientData(connectionString);
```

This is what I saw in an example, but that is not what I'm looking for because I want to encapsulate the concrete classes; I only want the Client to use the abstract class.  This is so I can support for more database systems in the future with minimal changes to the Client, and creating a new concrete class for the implementations.

I'm still learning, so there might be a lot of things wrong here. Please tell me how I can encapsulate all the concrete classes, and if there is anything wrong with my approach.

Many Thanks!

PS: I'm very excited to get into software architecture, but still am a beginner, so take it easy on me. :)

Comment: Since I want to completely encapsulate the concrete classes, is it still the Abstract Pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look something like this:

```
DatabaseWrapper dbClient = DBFactory.getInstance(DbType.SQL, connectionString);
```

Almost all design patters just introduce another layer of indirection and/or abstraction. In this case `DBFactory` is an abstraction layer that selects an appropriate implementation based on `DbType` enum.

Comment: Although Issac too had the write answer, I found it easier to use your implementation of using an enum DBType and used that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think that what you need is the Abstract Factory pattern.

Instead of:

```
DatabaseWrapper sqlClient = new SqlClientData(connectionString);
```

Use:

```
DatabaseWrapper sqlClient = DatabaseWrapper.create(connectionString);
```

And then encapsulate the creation logic inside the static "create" method.

Comment: Is Abstract Factory pattern same as Abstract pattern?

Comment: I believe it isn't. An "Abstract Factory" is, as it's named, a factory class; a class that is responsible for the construction of objects. "Abstract" is not, by itself, a design pattern. Abstract what? class? method? "Abstract" is just an adjective. :-)

Comment: +1 for mentioning Abstract Factory pattern. You would have got another +1 for saying that `abstract` is not a pattern (if it were possible to give another +1).

Comment: Thanks for making things clear. It always feels great to get a lesson from the pros! ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you have is already sufficient. You are only coupled to `SqlDataClient` at the time of construction, thereafter you would just pass `DatabaseWrapper` to all other classes/methods, and the rest of your code would not even know that is a `SqlDataClient`.

To switch to a different implementation, you only need to change the one line of construction code:

```
DatabaseWrapper client = new SqlClientData(connectionString);
```

to

```
DatabaseWrapper client = new MSAccessData(connectionString);
```

and the rest of your code will work unchanged.